# phpMyAdmin Error Code 403 When Trying SQL

Tags: phpmyadmin, centos

I installed `phpMyAdmin` with [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-with-apache-on-a-centos-7-server).

I secured it to my IP address in.

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf
```

I can log into my database with phpmyadmin and it works fine.

I can search, browse etc with phpmyadmin.  The exception is everytime I click on `SQL` I get.

```
Error in Processing Request
Error code: 403
Error text: Forbidden
```

I see this in the logs.
client denied by server configuration:

```
/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/db_sql.php
```

I can do all other functions with phpMyAdmin it seems like except SQL.  I even imported a database with it.  I just cannot click on SQL.

Searching the Internet I see this error many times reported but this is different.  Most get this error when trying to log into phpmyadmin.  I can log in fine I just cannot use SQL(db_sql.php) part of phpmyadmin.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the content of the file /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/db_sql.php ?

Comment: Yes I have.  It has same contents as another server that is working.  I have tried to compare all the settings that are different between but have come up with nothing yet.

Comment: Same problem. Except: `cat: /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/db_sql.php: No such file or directory`

Answer (score -1):

I had some configuration in httpd.conf i mistyped that was blocking access.

Comment: Ok. Sure would have been nice to know what that mistype was as this is the only page I can find on the entire internet where someone has this exact problem and I can't even begin to imagine what's mistyped in httpd.com.